# How to find limit of $a_n=\int_n^{n+1}f(x) $ where $(\forall x\ge0)~~ 0<f(x+1)<f(x) ~~~\text{and} \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$

Tags: calculus, limits

$f:[0,+\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ is a continous function that satisfies: $$(\forall x\ge0)~~ 0<f(x+1)<f(x) ~~~\text{and} \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$$

Sequence $a_n$ is defined as:

$$a_n=\int_n^{n+1}f(x) $$
$a_n$ is monotonous decreasing sequence.

$$a_{n+1}-a_n=\int_{n+1}^{n+2}f(x)-\int_n^{n+1}f(x)=\int_n^{n+1}f(x+1)-f(x)<0$$

It is bounded below by zero.
$$\int_n^{n+1}f(x)>\int_n^{n+1}0~=0$$

This shows that limit of $a_n$ exists. I don't know how to find this limit ?

Reccurence relation is an idea.

I don't know how to use the property $ \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$.

Comment: Try to guess the $inf\ {a_n\} .$ (use $f(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$)

Comment: My guess is zero

Comment: Use the definition of the above limit to show that all sufficiently large n you can have $f(x) < \epsilon $ for $x \in [n,n+1]$.

Comment: Use $\delta-\epsilon$ argument. And use that non-increasing bounded sequence converge to its $inf$.

Comment: What is the definition of $\int_n^{n+1} f(x)dx$? You made no continuity or measurability assumption.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}f(x)=0:$

$\epsilon >0$ given there is a  $M >0$, real, s.t for

$x \ge M:$ $|f(x)|<\epsilon$.

Let $n_0 >M$ ( Archimedean principle):

For $n\ge n_0$:

$0<a_n = \int_{n}^{n+1}|f(x)|dx < \epsilon \cdot 1.$